# how to solve Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Tags: javascript

When I create this code on JavaScript, that was working on the desktop browser but not working an the mobile browser

```
export class Global {
   
    static PeersIndex = new Array();
    static AudioTracks = new Array();
    static AudioTrack;
    static silenceAudioTrack;
    static client;
    static id;
    static mediastream;
    static MediaVideoStream;
    static MediaAudioStream;
    static VisualMedia;
    static capturestream = null;
    static MixAudio = new Event('onAudioMix');
    static username;
    static userid;
    static admin;
    static staticname;
    static vrecording;
    static arecording;
    static data;
    static getdata() {
        return this.data = {
            name: this.name,
            userid: this.userid,
            admin: this.admin,
            staticname: this.staticname,
            vrecording: this.vrecording,
            arecording: this.arecording
        }
    }

    static videoInput = new Array();
    static audioInput = new Array();
    static audioOutput = new Array();
    static Constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: false
    }
    static camAvailable = false;
    static micAvailable = false;

}
```

That could be an error at mobile device

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Which version of which mobile browser? And you've tagged this es5 but classes and static members weren't introduced until es6.

Comment: There is no `this` when you're dealing with `static` methods...

Comment: @HereticMonkey, there is.

Comment: @HereticMonkey `this` refers to the class object itself. I will grant you that no one in their right mind would write this code, but OP may have inherited it and it may not be worth changing.

Comment: Sorry, no *useful* `this`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error might be related to using the class field syntax, specifically the static class fields. Some older mobile devices may not support this syntax, leading to the syntax error.

To resolve this issue and make your code compatible with older JavaScript engines, you can use something like Babel.

Comment: This is a good guess, but OP hasn't given us enough to really be able to definitively answer.